# Remove consecutive duplicate words from a file using awk or sed

Tags: unix, awk

My input file looks like below:

```
“true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?”
```

Output shoud look like:

```
"true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good?"
```

i am trying the same with awk, but couldn't able to get the desired result.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s ",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}' input.txt
```

Could someone please help me here.

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: What would `true!@# true%&` output? `true%true%true%`? `true!true$true^`? or `true, true rohith`? The general question - what to do that thing that separates repeated words? Side note: I think this is hard.

Comment: Did you try using the `uniq` command?

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate?

Comment: There is no way to use uniq on "words". You would have to have words on separate lines.

Comment: What about pairs that are separated by a newline?  Are they to be replaced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    n = split($0,words,/[^[:alpha:]]+/,seps)
    prev = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        word = words[i]
        if (word != prev) {
            printf "%s%s", seps[i-1], word
        }
        prev = word
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
“true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good?”
```

Comment: That is an outstanding use of 'seps' in split(). Very smart.

Answer (score 3):

Just match the same backreference in sed:

```
sed ':l; s/\(^\|[^[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)[^[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\2\($\|[^[:alpha:]]\)/\1\2\3/g; tl'
```

How it works:

- `:l` - create a label `l` to jump to. See `tl` below.
- `s` - substitute

  - `/`
  - `\(^\|[^[:alpha:]]\)` - match beginning of the line or non-alphabetic character. This is so that the next part matches the whole word, not only suffix.
  - `\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\)` - match a word - one or more alphabetic characters.
  - `[^[:alpha:]]\{1,\}` - match a non-word - one or more non-alphabetic characters.
  - `\2` - match the same thing as in the second `\(...\)` - ie. match the word.
  - `\($\|[^[:alpha:]]\)` - match the end of the line or match a non-alphabetic character. That is so we match the whole second word, not only it's prefix.
  - `/`
  - `\1\2\3` - substitute it for `<beginning of the line or non-alphabetic prefix character><the word><end of the line or non-alphabetic suffix character found>`
  - `/`
  - `g` - substitute globally. But, because regex is never going back, it will substitute 2 words at a time.
- `tl` - Jump to label `l` if last `s` command was successfull. This is here, so that when there are 3 words the same, like `true true true`, they are properly replaced by a single `true`.

Without the `\(^\|[^[:alpha:]]\)` and `\($\|[^[:alpha:]]\)`, without them for example `true rue` would be substituted by `true`, because the suffix `rue rue` would match.

Below are my other solution, which also remove repeated words across lines.

My first solution was with `uniq`. So first I will transform the input into pairs with the format `<non-alphabetical sequence separating words encoded in hex> <a word>`. Then run it via `uniq -f1` with ignoring first field and then convert back. This will be very slow:

```
# recreate input
cat <<EOF |
true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?
EOF
# insert zero byte after each word and non-word
# the -z option is from GNU sed
sed -r -z 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\x00&\x00/g' |
# for each pair (non-word, word)
xargs -0 -n2 sh -c '
    # ouptut hexadecimal representation of non-word
    printf "%s" "$1" | xxd -p | tr -d "\n"
    # and output space with the word
    printf " %s\n" "$2"
' -- |
# uniq ignores empty fields - so make sure field1 always has something
sed 's/^/-/' |
# uniq while ignoring first field
uniq -f1 |
# for each pair (non-word in hex, word)
xargs -n2 bash -c '
    # just `printf "%s" "$1" | sed 's/^-//' | xxd -r -p` for posix shell
    # change non-word from hex to characters
    printf "%s" "${1:1}" | xxd -r -p
    # output word
    printf "%s" "$2"
' --
```

But then I noticed that `sed` is doing a good job at tokenizing the input - it places zero bytes between each word and non-word tokens. So I could easily read the stream. I can ignore repeated words in awk by reading zero separated stream in GNU awk and comparing the last readed word:

```
cat <<EOF |
true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?
EOF
sed -r -z 's/[[:alpha:]]+/\x00&\x00/g' |
gawk -vRS='\0' '
NR%2==1{
    nonword=$0
}
NR%2==0{
    if (length(lastword) && lastword != $0) {
        printf "%s%s", lastword, nonword
    }
    lastword=$0
}
END{
    printf "%s%s", lastword, nonword
}'
```

In place of zero byte something unique could be used as record separator, for example `^` character, that way it could be used with non-GNU awk version, tested with mawk available on repl. Shortened the script by using shorter variable names here:

```
cat <<EOF |
true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?
EOF
sed -r 's/[[:alpha:]]+/^&^/g' |
awk -vRS='^' '
    NR%2{ n=$0 }
    NR%2-1 && length(l) && l != $0 { printf "%s%s", l, n }
    NR%2-1 { l=$0 }
    END { printf "%s%s", l, n }
'
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/RightOverdueWebpage). The snippets output:

```
true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good?
```

Comment: Would you mind detailing the sed expression you write right at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: `RS='^'` means the record is split at every `^` character, but there's no particular reason to think `^` can't appear in the input, you'd be better off using some control-character as that's probably less likely to appear.. Never use a variable named `l` btw as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: @rvbarreto There is a whole explanation in points below, i have tried to explain it. Maybe there is something that I could try to explain better?

Comment: @KamilCuk that was perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Simple `sed`:

```
echo "true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?" | sed -r 's/(\w+) (\1)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you have shown in output but is close using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v RS='[^-_[:alnum:]]+' '$1 == p{printf "%s", RT; next} {p=$1; ORS=RT} 1' file
```

```
“true , rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good ?”
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/(\w+) *\1/\1/g' sample.txt
```

sample.txt

```
“true true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good good?”
```

output:

```
:~$ sed -E 's/(\w+) *\1/\1/g' sample.txt
“true, rohith Rohith;
cold burn, and fact and fact good?”
```

**Explanation**

`(\w) *\1` - matches a word separated by a space of the same word and saves it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your expected input, this might work:

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)( *)\1/\1\2/g ; s/ ([.,;:])/\1/g ; s/  / /g' myfile
```

**([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)** = words that might be repeated.

**( *)\1** = check if the previous word is repeated after a space.

**s/ ([.,;:])/\1/g** = removes extra spaces before punctuation (you might want to add characters to this group).

**s/  / /g** = removes double spaces.

This works with GNU sed.